# Share Global variables

Tags: variables, lua, share

How to share global variables between two different lua_state?

The lua_state can not be created with lua_newthread.

Help please

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly share components from one `lua_State` with another. The only cross connection you can have between `lua_State`s is via the intervention of some C or C++ code. You can register the same function in multiple states, and thereby access the same resource from both. But you have to do it through functions and C/C++/etc objects, not directly through Lua.